# Find the tag element and append new element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li>
   <a>Parent Node</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a>Child 1</a></li>
     ***<li><a>Child 2</a></li>***
   </ul>
</li>
```

I need to find 'UL' tag and I want to appendTo Child 3 inside 'Ul' at run time.

I'm able to insert the first child but Second child is not inserting.

Can anybody help on this?? thanks..

Comment: make snippet or update this with your code http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/qbmuwy00/

Comment: Please show some effort you've made instead of just asking others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:nth-child() Selector` to achieve this as in this:

```js
// Javascript

$("ul li:nth-child(2)").append("<li><a>Child 3</a></li>");
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a>Parent Node</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Child 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Child 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("ul").append('<li><a>Child3</a></li>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a>parent Node</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Child1</a></li>
    <li><a>Child2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: why he is downvoted? I checked his answer in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/52au4yef/ its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your image. Do you looking for the :nth-child(3) selector ?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer